# RDD join, not returning keys, that have an ID starting with a letter

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, rdd

I am seeing quite a strange issue using spark joins when joining RDDs.
I have two RDDs with the same key, one from a server access logs showing what a client has attempted to purchase, with a specific order ID as added by the client, with the structure as below:
OrderKey(ClientID,UserID,ClientsOrderID,ItemOrdered,Price), OrderValues(Nanosecond timestamp, latency timestamp, grouping number)

Examples are as the below:

```
(OrderKey(CLI1,USR1,BDC11111222,APPLE,0.8031),OrderValues(1431698956999379357,12176,143169895699))
(OrderKey(CLI1,USR1,PRO22222223333,PEAR,0.8031),OrderValues(1431698956999367181,0,143169895699))
(OrderKey(CLI3,USR1,10000956556,ORANGE,4.0555),OrderValues(1431676103249289077,132193,143167610324))
(OrderKey(CLI2,USR2,PRO33335555,ORANGE,0.8031),OrderValues(1431698956999369005,1824,143169895699))
(OrderKey(CLI4,USR1,418,ORANGE,0.8038),OrderValues(1431676103249156884,0,143167610324))
(OrderKey(CLI5,USR1,15D11111999,TOMATO,0.8052),OrderValues(1431651108750149274,0,143165110875))
(OrderKey(CLI6,USR2,21698,TOMATO,0.8052),OrderValues(1431651108749265019,10976,143165110874))
```

I then try to join the data to my DB data on when the order was actually made. This has the same Order Key, but it's value is the DB details:

DbDetails(dbOrderDateTime,dbOrderNo,quantity,hasBeenDelivered, typeOfDelivery)

```
(OrderKey(CLI1,USR1,BDC11111222,APPLE,0.8031),DbDetails(15-may-15 14:09:17.002,877490,1,false,AUTOMATIC))
(OrderKey(CLI1,USR1,PRO22222223333,PEAR,0.8031),DbDetails(15-may-15 14:09:17.002,877487,1,false,AUTOMATIC))
(OrderKey(CLI3,USR1,10000956556,ORANGE,4.0555),DbDetails(15-may-15 07:48:23.251,255857,2,false,AUTOMATIC))
(OrderKey(CLI2,USR2,PRO33335555,ORANGE,0.8031),DbDetails(15-may-15 14:09:17.002,877488,1,false,AUTOMATIC))
(OrderKey(CLI4,USR1,418,ORANGE,0.8038),DbDetails(15-may-15 07:48:23.251,822188,1,false,AUTOMATIC))
(OrderKey(CLI5,USR1,15D11111999,TOMATO,0.8052),DbDetails(15-may-15 00:51:48.752,769075,1,false,AUTOMATIC))
(OrderKey(CLI6,USR2,21698,TOMATO,0.8052),DbDetails(15-may-15 00:51:48.752,769070,1,false,AUTOMATIC))
```

I am attempting to join the RDDs like the below:

```
val fullOrderDetails = accessRDD.join(dbRDD).map{
  case (orderKey,dbDetails) =>
    FullOrderDetails(
      dbDetails._1.orderDate,
      orderKey.clientName, orderKey.userName,orderKey.market,dbDetails._1.orderID,
      rK.clientOrderID,orderKey.price,  dbDetails._1.orderQty,
      dbDetails._1.entryType,      dbDetails._1.versionReason,dbDetails._1.userType,
      dbDetails._2.accessTs,dbDetails._2.krakenTsDelta, dbDetails._2.groupingNumber 
    )
}
```

Any idea, why the only results that are returned are the ones that start with numbers when I output the resulting RDD?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean _start with numbers_? What is `OrderKey` , `DbDetails`, `FullOrderDetails`? Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first set of examples is `accessRDD` and your second set of examples is `dbRDD`, your casing seems wrong on the subsequent `map`. It should be:

```
...
case (orderKey: OrderKey, (orderValues: OrderValues, dbDetails: DbDetails)) =>
...
```

This is because `join` generates a pair RDD with the values being a `Tuple2` of the values of the joining factions.

Comment: Rohan, thanks for the scala style advice. It turns out it was not the issue, but it was the formatting of the user names. It has been fixed and it now works.